How to Change React Context State without Re-rendering?
I have a context provider wrapped around 2 components. One component (Thing) calls the state setter function and the other (Thing2) displays the value of the state.
Why do both components re-render when state changes even though only 1 component is actually changing?
How do I stop the component that triggers the state change (Thing) from re-rendering?
let localBoo = false;

type MyContext = {
    boo: boolean;
    setBoo: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};

const MyContext = createContext<MyContext | undefined>(undefined);

const MyContextProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
    const [boo, setBoo] = useState(localBoo);

    return (<MyContext.Provider value={{ boo, setBoo }} children={children} />);
};

const Thing = () => {
    const { setBoo } = useContext(MyContext)!;

    console.log("render Thing");

    const handleOnClick = () => {
        localBoo = !localBoo;
        setBoo(localBoo);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Push</button>
        </>
    );
};

const Thing2 = () => {
    const { boo } = useContext(MyContext)!;

    console.log("render Thing 2");

    return (
        <>
            <p>boo: {boo ? "true" : "false"}</p>
        </>
    );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider>
       <Thing />
       <Thing2 />
    </MyContext.Proivder>
  );
};


In React Context, any context state that changes will trigger a re-render for all components that use the context, whether they use the particular value you’re changing or not. To achieve what you are looking for, you might want to take a look at other components that handle state changes a little differently and more controlled eg Solidjs.

Both components consume the same context. When you click on the Push button, the context's state is updated, which triggers a re-render of all components that consume the context.
